# WinSCP as a superuser

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, winscp

[image]

I have come across WinSCP (http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) which I think is a fantastic client to work with my EC2 ubuntu instance as a graphical alternative to putty. One problem though is that every time I want to modify or create a file I have to drop into a shell and run the appropriate sudo command. Is there a way to login with winscp as a superuser to avoid this?

Comment: See [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

Comment: http://cvlive.blogspot.de/2014/03/how-to-login-in-as-ssh-root-user-from.html